# Random Forest Regressor, trying to get trees text out

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
model=RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
model.score(X_test,y_test)

feature_list = list(X.columns)


r = export_text(model, feature_names=feature_list,
            decimals=0, show_weights=True)
print(r)

AttributeError: 'RandomForestRegressor' object has no attribute 'tree_'
```

Any idea what I'm missing here? I am trying to get tree text data out of a random forest regressor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RandomForestRegressor` is trained by fitting multiple trees, hence it doesn't make sense to try to directly `export_text` from the classifier. Indeed as the error points out, it does not have the attribute `tree_`. Note that, as mentioned in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_text.html) it is used to:

> Build a text report showing the rules of a **decision tree**

`export_text` works with decision trees, so if you instead used one of the `RandomForest`'s estimators as `model` argument it would work:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import export_text
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
X = iris['data']
y = iris['target']
rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0, max_depth=2)

rf.fit(X, y)
r = export_text(rf.estimators_[0], feature_names=iris['feature_names'])
print(r)

|--- petal width (cm) <= 0.75
|   |--- class: 0.0
|--- petal width (cm) >  0.75
|   |--- petal length (cm) <= 4.85
|   |   |--- class: 1.0
|   |--- petal length (cm) >  4.85
|   |   |--- class: 2.0
```

Though of course this is *only* one of the estimators that have been fit by the classifier, and does not represent the criteria followed by the classifier, which is an [ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) of multiple trees.