# Write random forest tree into excel

Tags: python, excel, scikit-learn, random-forest

```
model = RandomForestRegressor()    
model.fit(X, y)
r = export_text(model.estimators_[0], feature_names=feature_list)
```

[image]

I am trying to convert the Random Forest regression tree into a if-then-else statements in excel sheet:

```
r.to_excel("trees.xlsx")

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

Also I tried the following to get r exactly as it displays in print to an excel.

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 0
col = 0
for x in r():
   worksheet.write(row, col,     str(x[0]))
   worksheet.write(row, col + 1, str(x[1]))
row += 1
workbook.close()

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: There is not any "RFR tree" - please avoid using custom & ad-hoc abbreviations (you can abbreviate random forest to RF though). Please clarify exactly what `r` is (preferably show how it is cerated). See how to create a [MCVE]), or include explicitly a link to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61754908/random-forest-regressor-trying-to-get-trees-text-out).

Comment: I am not sure that calling random function names counts as an example of what you have tried. Please make an actual attempt of writing code that have a reasonable chance of working. My guess is that there are better ways to traverse your data model than a textual tree.

Comment: I was trying to first explore in excel but youre right, let me try that. thanks!